# Extract variable names from java expression dinamically

Tags: java, string, lexical-analysis

I have dynamic set of string expressions(java code parts)
eg :

```
val1.subtract(val2.divide(val3,6,java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP) ,new MathContext(6, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

I want to extract variable names from each expression using java. For above example, output should be:

```
[val1,val2,val3]
```

How do I address this issue?

**note :**

varible names could be any java accepted ones. No any patterns

Comment: Are they all the form `valXX` where XX are digits ?

Comment: No specific pattern. They could be anything that java accepts as a variable name

Answer (score 2):

A string which forms a valid java expression requires a complete java parser, capable of parsing every aspect of the entire java language.

This is a valid expression:

```
new Object() {
    public int test() {
        return 5;
    }
}.test();
```

Its type is `int`, and it would evaluate to `5`.

You can write anything inside those braces. Including new types.

Thus, there are only two answers available:

- Define a restricted set of operations, which means you no longer have 'a java expression', but, a 'NilankaManoj expression'. You'd have to write the spec: Which bits are and are not allowed? Without that spec, your question isn't answerable.
- Alternatively, you really do want **any** java expression, in which case, search the web for an open source java parser. Various parser libraries such as ANTLR 'ship' with a java grammar which is usually out of date and not quite complete. Alternatively, get `ecj` which is open source. All of these are complex beasts with a very significant learning curve.